# TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in `React JS` and I'm trying learn how to work with state and use state in react but I keep getting error `cannot set property of state of undefined`

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  this.state = {
    buttonColor: 'lightgreen'
  }
 
  const changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({buttonColor: this.state.buttonColor = 'lightblue'});
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={()=>changeColor()}  
            style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.buttonColor }} 
            className="btn text-white mt-5 ml-5">
      Change Color
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a function component or a class component? Your issue is basically that you're mixing the syntaxes of them.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above method of setting state *would* work *if* you were using a [class based react component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

But you are using a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), so it does not work.

This is how you could do the same thing with a react function component and the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("lightgreen");

  const changeColor = () => setButtonColor("lightblue");

  return (
    <button
      onClick={changeColor}
      style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
    >
      Change Color
    </button>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Remember to [read the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

[image: Edit adoring-dew-3g7qc]